# Could there be something like the Higgs field which gives particles their energy in a similar way the Higgs boson gives particles their mass?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, higgs

First of all, in no way do I have advanced knowledge of particle physics, quantum mechanics, or any other necessary scientific concept for a full understanding of this question. Secondly, this is purely hypothetical; I am a fiction writer looking to explore fictional concepts that are *guided* by science, not strictly within its realm.

What conditions would there need to be for the existence of this field? Could it exist without changing existing, fundamental laws? Keep in mind that, as it's fiction, new processes can exist to allow it. I understand that the Higgs Boson does not *literally* give particles mass; i.e: there aren't Higgs Bosons clustered around particles and making them massive.

I'm guessing there's something fundamentally wrong with this question (meaning my understanding of energy and mass) that makes it unanswerable or difficult to answer directly. If you can find a way around it, hats off to you! And thanks very much to anyone who answers at all. Again, I really have no idea what I'm talking about, so feel free to brush the question off as complete nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could there be something like the Higgs field which gives particles their energy in a similar way the Higgs boson gives particles their mass?

Lets take the misunderstandings in this title. The higgs boson does not give particles their mass, it it the Higgs field that is involved in that.

The mass of the quantum mechanical particles is constant, does not change in time and space. The Higgs field gave masses to particles once , in the cosmological model of [the Big Bang](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html)

[image: bb]

When the electroweak interaction spontaneously broke, at about $10^{-12}$ secods after the Big Bang. After that time the particles have the masses [fixed in the table .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle)

Mass is a scalar. Energy is a vector component in the [relativistic four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) describing each particle. Mass is the length of the relativistic four vector.

Energy and momentum are conserved variables that depend on particle interactions to change their value, according to the conservation laws and the quantum mechanical wavefunction describing the interaction.

So the answer is :no, there can be no similarity even if we correct the title and talk of Higgs fields.

By the way, the Higgs **boson** discovered a while ago at CERN validated the standard model that is based on the Higgs **field**. The boson is the expression of the Higgs field , the way the electron is the expression of the electron field. Particle creation and annihilation operators create the particles acting on the  all-permeating fields.

Good luck with your fiction.